# Does extension in vscode affect to the remote server?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm wondering if the VSCode extension installation affects the remote server.

I already connected to the server using remote ssh and tried debugging the Python file.
When I tried to run the Python code in VSCode, there was an error message that I should install the Python extension for the following process.
But I'm worried whether the Python extension affects the version of Python in the remote server because I share the server with others.
Does the Python extension in the VSCode independent of the Python in the system?

[image]

Comment: the python extension does not have a python interpreter, it uses the python interpreter installed in the OS or via a virtual environment

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for your comment! You mean that the Python extension follows the Python version in the local or remote server without any modification, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not affect your use, you can install it in the extension stroe.

VS Code runs extensions in one of two places: locally on the UI / client side, or remotely on the SSH host. While extensions that affect the VS Code UI, like themes and snippets, are installed locally, most extensions will reside on the SSH host. This ensures you have smooth experience and allows you to install any needed extensions for a given workspace on an SSH host from your local machine.

If you install an extension from the Extensions view, it will automatically be installed in the correct location.

You can read [document about managing extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! In my case, the extension will run remotely on the SSH host.

Comment: it is not the Extensions bar that determines where the extension is installed, the extension determines where it wants to be installed: UI or remote